# Optimized way to read settings from database only once in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a big project with several http servers that use one main sql database.

The project has many settings that are frequently used(almost every request).
The settings are stored in the main sql database.

I wanted to know, if there is some way to initialize settings only once in php, because it makes no sense for every request to go and read same setting from sql server over and over again, it feels like a waste of resources.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 solutions:

1. Create a (perhaps also PHP) script that exports settings from database into a plain text file, and includes that file on every http server;
2. use a memory cache server like http://memcached.org/ and preload data there from an external script, then have http servers connect to memcache instead of SQL.

Edit: Other than that, PHP does not give you  a real web application, where you "run" your application and it has its own memory and persistant, global variables. This is one of the reasons I personally got tired of PHP and moved to Python (and Django, specifically).

Comment: Or use APC. memcached has the benefit of being shared among the web servers whereas APC benefits from being local, i.e. does not fetch information through a network connection and therefore possibly reducing latency. Files may be slow as well, YMMV.

Comment: You moved away from PHP because it doesn't have persistent global variables? Yikes. There are lots of reasons to quit PHP, but lack of globals isn't a good one.

Comment: "one of the reasons", as I wrote. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard code these settings in your PHP code.

```
// Your current code, somthing like this:
$setting_1 = getDataFromMySQL('setting1');

// Hard coded
$setting_1 = TRUE;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think hardcoding anything is a valid solution ever.

Comment: @gnur Hard-coding things via `define` is just another tool, saying it's not a valid solution *ever* is every bit as wrong as saying "hard code everything all the time".

Comment: I don't think defining constants in 1 constant is considered hardcoding

Comment: @gnur: How would you avoid calling a expensive datastore for values which are never changing other than saving them directly in the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php) in php if it is compiled that way.

Another possibility is that you store a **combined** value of your settings as PHP code in one field (a PHP array for example), then you can read them all with only one query to the DB server. Of course this cached value have to be updated when settings change.

Answer (score 0):

APC is the best solution if you are using a single server, otherwise I would go with memcached. However, you may also consider a MYSQL memory table, it is very efficient for fast reads and writes. Another solution is using Linux to keep and call settings with Linux exec. However, this might be a trouble and there might be some security issues. Also let me remind you that efficient INNODB indexes can help you a lot. MYISAM is also considered a good "read" performer, however my benchmarks show me that INNODB indexes are faster.

Comment: exec()? So instead of hitting the database repeatedly to retrieve information, you want to spawn a subshell, invoke another program, parse its output, etc...? This is more efficient how?

Comment: you think when you call any mysql function you don't do anything and just hitting the DB? even parsing the query is a huge bootneck for mysql. Linux kernel keeps desired values in memory and when exec method calls any related function in shell Linux prints it and PHP parser gets value and prints. Actually it is much more easier than hitting DB. PHP is linux native language and and when you read about MYSQL Internals you would get better what I mean. Also as I mentioned using INNODB indexes are huge improvement since indexes are just bullseye for reading DB. Just benchmark!

Answer (score -1):

You can store the settings in the user's session -

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['settings'])) {
  $settings_array = //pulled from database
  $_SESSION['settings'] = $settings_array;
}
```

That way, it'll only query once per user

Comment: This is technically possible; this will, however, create a copy of the settings for *every* user that connects to the server  and sounds like a horrible RAM hogging for no purpose (at least nothing in original post suggests this is needeed); the RAM would also probably *not* be freed up as soon as the page loads.

Comment: The session is for persisting user-specific data. It shouldn't be viewed as "free" storage for dumping cache data, there are *far* more efficient ways of caching things.

Comment: Sessions are stored on disk, not in RAM.  Yes, it will create a copy for each user - however, I'd be surprised if it actually filled a significant amount of storage space.

Comment: You don't think 10,000 duplications of identical cached setting data is a problem? Never mind that there is no easy way to sweep the cache out when the settings change. The session is not a suitable place to cache site-wide data.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a session to store those settings.